# NULL value somehow being assigned to ID field in H2 database SQL statement

Tags: javascript, java, sql, angularjs, h2

I'm working on an H2 database, trying to get it to accept input from a webpage, and it keeps giving me the following error:

```
Caused by[m: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: NULL not allowed for column "ID"; SQL statement:
insert into BOOK (ID, AUTHOR, GENRE, ILLUSTRATOR, SERIES, TITLE) values (default, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23502-214]
```

and I have no idea where it's getting this NULL value from. I've got the model kitted out

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BOOK")
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;
```

and the DAO is set up to give me a non-null value

```
@Repository
public class DAOImpl implements DAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void saveBook(Book book) {
        book.setId(0L);
        
        Session s = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        s.save(book);
    }
```

It just seems like the NULL is coming out of nowhere. What am I missing?

Comment: the SQL being generated dutifully tells h2 to use the defined default value, and that is, evidently, `NULL`. It's not java that generates these IDs. The `CREATE TABLE` statement did not set up the column to be auto-counting / to default to `NEXTVAL(someSequence)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check definition of your table. Because you use `GenerationType.IDENTITY`, the `ID` column must be defined as an *identity column*:

```sql
CREATE TABLE BOOK (
    ID BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    .....
);
```

If you want to prevent attempts to insert custom values instead of generated ones, you can use `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY` instead.